# How to attach event dynamically in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying overwrite links (transform in ajax links) but when I try to add an event to a tag nothing happens.

My script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        $j(".will_paginate_styles a").each(function() {
            if (this.innerText.length > 1) {
                this.style.padding = "8px 6px 10px 6px";
                var url = this.href + "&category_id=<%= 1 %>";
                this.href = "#";
                jQuery(this).live("click",
                     function(){
                                new Ajax.Request(url, {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:'authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('uurmOp9OrgS1CRpcpKdMN9PHlMTt+lkHjhYdNgP+LbQ=')}); return false;
                               }
                );
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

How could I attach a event to this tag or transform the link to ajax link? Any suggestions?

Comment: i think that you need to put tag name first $j("a.will_paginate_styles")

Comment: You are using `$j` did you alias jquery to `$j` somewhere earlier in your code?  You have a very strange mix of jquery and non-jquery.

Comment: Does the $j(".will_paginate_styles a") selector match any elements?

Comment: It might be helpful to show the code for Ajax.Request

Comment: To test if your selector returns one or more elements, alert its size : `$j(".will_paginate_styles a").size();`

Comment: Excuse me i need to use alias for jQuery because i am workin on rails 2.3.9 which use prototype. My problem is: When i try attach click event to link 'on fly' don´t happen nothing.

Comment: Thanks This problem is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using JQuery.

This line belongs to prototype library

```
new Ajax.Request(url, {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:'authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('uurmOp9OrgS1CRpcpKdMN9PHlMTt+lkHjhYdNgP+LbQ=')}); return false;
```

SO I replace this line for his equivalent in jQuery:

```
$.ajax(url: "www.myurl.com", data: { data1: "data1", etc: "etc"})
```

Obviously there are avalaible more options in this method. Read JQuery official documentation